# How to see the console output during a test execution in C# Class Library Project

Tags: c#, .net-core, nunit

`Console.WriteLine()`

`TestContext.WriteLine()`

The above code writes to Test Explorer output only after the test execution.

Is there anyway to see the console logs during execution?. If a test is executing for a long time. I need to wait till the execution complete in order to see the logs.

I am using a Nunit Test Project(.Net Core)

Answer (score 0):

`TestContext.Progress.Write("my outputs");`

Using this line of code from Nunit.I am able to output the logs to Output->Test Window during execution.